# Deduplicate a large set of documents (Python)

Tags: python, duplicates

does anyone know or point me in the direction of a means of checking if a new document already exists in a large set of documents? The set of documents will only change when a new unique document is added, so I was thinking perhaps using document signatures to avoid 1-1 comparisons?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give some more details... Where are your documents stored? On a DB, on a filesystem directory, or what? And how do you recognize if the "new" document is really new or a duplicate? By name, or some other easy to check attributes? Or you may want to store a hash value for each doc?

Comment: It's stored in a filesystem directory. I'm actually interested in learning what would be a good way to compare files swiftly, thus the "how" is part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relatively quick way is to store for each document in your set a hash value, perhaps MD5 or the one of your choice (Python now even offers BLAKE2). If the doc set is large you may want to store those values in a DB, but now for simplicity I will assume we have them in a dictionary with the hash as key and the list of corresponding filenames as value (we may have collisions, hence the list).

So when you need to check for a new doc you just calculate its hash, and check if it already is in the dictionary. If no, you're sure the doc is new; if yes, it may be a collision, so you'll need a full-text comparison of the relevant docs.

A sample code:

```
from hashlib import md5
def check_new(f):
    with open(f) as newfile:
        newtxt = newfile.read()
        h = md5(newtxt).hexdigest()
        if h not in store:
            print('adding...')
        else:
            for colliding in store[h]:
                with open(colliding) as oldfile:
                    oldtxt = oldfile.read()
                    if newtxt == oldtxt:
                        break
            else:
                print('adding...')
```

Just one note: hash functions work on `bytes` so you will want to encode/decode your texts